# Netty - Skip the rest of the handlers in the pipeline

Tags: asynchronous, netty

I'm currently using Netty 4.0 if that matters but anyways..

I have a handler written like so that I want to filter out requests depending on the URI:

```
public class URIFilterHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<HttpRequest> {

public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, HttpRequest req) {
    String uri = req.uri();

    if (uri.contains("abcde")) {
        HttpResponse response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        ctx.writeAndFlush(response);
        // HERE IS WHERE I WANT TO SKIP REST OF THE HANDLERS

    } else {
        ctx.fireChannelRead(req);
    }
}
}
```

And then here is my pipeline

```
public class ServerInitializer extends ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> {

    @Override
    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) {
        ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();

        p.addLast(new HttpRequestDecoder());
        p.addLast(new HttpResponseEncoder());
        p.addLast(new URIFilterHandler());
        p.addLast(new HttpObjectAggregator(1048576));
        p.addLast(new RequestHandler());

    }
}
```

I tried the following, but it seemed to permanently remove these handlers from the pipeline and not just for the one request.

```
       ctx.pipeline().remove(HttpObjectAggregator.class);
       ctx.pipeline().remove(RequestHandler.class;)
```

I tried using ctx.channel().close() and ctx.fireChannelInactive() to no avail.  It seems to still pass the request onto the next handler (HttpObjectAggregator in this case).  I think it's possibly being due to the close() and fireChannelInactive() being asynchronous?

EDIT: It seems the issue I was having was I was sending back a DefaultHttpResponse.  When I sent back a DefaultFullHttpResponse, the request never hangs.

Answer (score 5):

To skip the rest of the handlers, just do nothing. To continue to handle data with the next handler, with the initial object or with one another, call `ctx.fireChannelRead( object )`

Take care of reference counted objects. `SimpleChannelInboundHandler` release by default the input (depending on constructor parameters). If you decide to fire it to the next handler, you must call `ReferenceCountUtil.retain(Object)`. 
See documentation here: http://netty.io/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html

Moreover, I think you should put the `HttpObjectAggregator` handler before your own handler on pipeline, and make your handler catching `FullHttpRequest`.
`HttpObjectAggregator` handles all http chuncks for you and puts on pipeline a `FullHttpRequest`. In your case, it may be interessing because if you ignore one chunck, what do you do with others chuncks already aggregated on pipeline ?  I guess you may have a DecoderException thrown if you do nothing.

Comment: The ReferenceCountUtil.retain(Object) was helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't call `ctx.fireChannelRead()` in `channelRead0`, then the message will not be propagated to the following handlers. This can  be demonstrated with the following code snippet,  where the first handler filters out all odd numbers:

```
    EmbeddedChannel channel = new EmbeddedChannel(
            new SimpleChannelInboundHandler<Integer>() {
                @Override
                protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
                        Integer msg) throws Exception {
                    if (msg % 2 == 0)
                        ctx.fireChannelRead(msg);
                }
            },
            new ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, 
                       Object msg) throws Exception {
                    System.out.println(msg);
                }
            });

    channel.writeInbound(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
```

Comment: The next handler is the HttpObjectAggregator.  I get this exception:

io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: io.netty.handler.codec.MessageAggregationExceptionat io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:99)

Which seems to indicate that it is being passed onto the next handler even though I'm not firing ctx.fireChannelRead()

I should also add that the HTTP response is being correctly returned, but I see the exception in the logs

Comment: Seem to have found a solution.. instead of extending SimpleChannelInboundHandler, extend ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter and override channelRead (as opposed to channelRead0).  This is because the implementation of channelRead seems to call fireChannelRead by default.

Comment: Hmm, the above method doesn't seem to pass the message on to the other handlers when I want it to even though I am calling ctx.fireChannelRead() and the request just hangs